# Rest assured API to get a element from Json response

Tags: api-testing, rest, json, rest-assured

I'm using `restassured.path.json.JsonPath` extractor

From the below response I would like to extract the `customerProductIdentifier` where `highLevelProduct` is `HSI`,

```
{
    "recordsChoice": [
        {
            "listedName": "EMA WATSON",
            "address": {
                "streetAddress": "",
                "addressLine1": "1900 SKY FLOWER CT",
                "addressLine2": "LAS VEGAS, NV"
            },
            "recordIdentifier": "310290154",
            "accountStatus": "Open"
        }
    ],
    "rxSessionIdentifier": "33062565",
    "accountInformation": {
        "billingIdentifier": "310290154",
        "billingName": "HANDY SHOWROOM",
        "billingAddress": {
            "streetAddress": "",
            "addressLine1": "1900 SKY FLOWER CT",
            "addressLine2": "LAS VEGAS, NV"
        },
        "customerType": "Consumer",
        "customerSubType": "Regular",
        "allServicesDeniedForNonPayment": false,
        "accountStatus": "Open",
        "isMilitaryAccount": false,
        "primaryClassOfServiceCode": "N.A",
        "classOfService": "N.A",
        "usocsOnAccount": [
            "IL",
            "WA"
        ],
        "hasPrism": true,
        "isMadisonRiverCustomer": false,
        "customerDateTime": "01/02/2019 03:58",
        "customerTimeGMTOffset": "-08:00",
        "customerTimeZoneAbbreviation": "US/Pacific",
        "legacyDispatchTerritory": "QCENTER",
        "billingSystem": "QCENTER",
        "smsDigitalDialogPreferences": {
            "repairSubscription": false,
            "defaultContact": false,
            "invalidFlag": false,
            "billingSubscription": false,
            "orderSubscription": false
        },
        "emailDigitalDialogPreferences": {
            "subscribedEmail": "hotel_reserv@hathway.com",
            "repairSubscription": true,
            "defaultContact": true,
            "marketingSubscription": true,
            "billingSubscription": true,
            "orderSubscription": true
        }
    },
    "serviceLines": [
        {
            "centralOffice": "LVSSNV",
            "locationTimeZone": "US/Pacific",
            "serviceAddress": {
                "streetAddress": "",
                "addressLine1": "1210 STRATOSPHERE",
                "city": "LAS VEGAS",
                "stateProvince": "NV",
                "postalCode": "89123-3959",
                "countryCode": "USA"
            },
            "hasGPON": false,
            "accessTech": "ADSL2PB",
            "hasVectoring": false,
            "isNIC": false,
            "isClickConverted": true,
            "isPrivateCarriage": false,
            "isVISP": false,
            "hasProfile17a": false,
            "hasInsideWireMaintenancePlan": true,
            "serviceTnOrCktId": "8861061786",
            "customerProducts": [
                {
                    "customerProductIdentifier": "314417931",
                    "ossProfile": {
                        "ossProfileName": "TraditionalEnsembleClick",
                        "billingSource": "Ansemble",
                        "inventorySource": "MARTENS",
                        "ticketingSystem": "OneRemedy",
                        "dispatchSystem": "Click"
                    },
                   "usoc": "WA",
                    "otherUsocs": [],
                    "highLevelProduct": "HSI",
                    "isActive": true,
                    "activationDate": "12/12/1985 00:00",
                    "productStatus": "Active",
                    "hasAtEaseFeature": false,
                    "purchasedSpeedDownKbps": "10000",
                    "purchasedSpeedUpKbps": "768",
                    "connectionType": "IPOE",
                    "isCentralizedBRAS": "false",
                    "sourceOfOpenSessionInfo": "BRAS"
                },
                {
                    "customerProductIdentifier": "314417930",
                    "ossProfile": {
                        "ossProfileName": "TraditionalEnsembleClick",
                        "billingSource": "Ensemble",
                        "inventorySource": "FCAS",
                        "ticketingSystem": "JACKS",
                        "dispatchSystem": "Click"
                    },
                    "usoc": "IL",
                    "otherUsocs": [],
                    "highLevelProduct": "VOICE",
                    "isActive": true,
                    "activationDate": "09/21/2014 00:00",
                    "productStatus": "Active",
                    "hasAtEaseFeature": false
                },
                {
                    "customerProductIdentifier": "314417929",
                    "ossProfile": {
                        "ossProfileName": "TraditionalEnsembleClick",
                        "billingSource": "Ansemble",
                        "inventorySource": "FCAS",
                        "ticketingSystem": "JACKS",
                        "dispatchSystem": "Click"
                    },
                    "usoc": "IL",
                    "otherUsocs": [],
                    "highLevelProduct": "CTL_PRISM",
                    "isActive": true,
                    "activationDate": "09/21/2014 00:00",
                    "productStatus": "Active",
                    "hasAtEaseFeature": false,
                    "connectionType": "IPOE",
                    "isCentralizedBRAS": "false",
                    "sourceOfOpenSessionInfo": "BRAS"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "apiResponse": {
        "code": 0,
        "type": "S",
        "message": "Success"
    }
}
```

I have this code to extract the `billingName` and `rxSessionIdentifier` from the response, but I'm not sure how to extract the `customerProductIdentifier` where `highLevelProduct` is `HSI`

```
extract().response();

        String responseString=res.asString();
        System.out.println(responseString);

         //To grab the particular parameters from the response
        JsonPath js = new JsonPath(responseString);
        // To extract the billing name
        String billingName = js.get("accountInformation.billingName");
        System.out.println("Billing Name of the customer is " +billingName);

        // To extract the session id
        String rxSessionIdentifier = js.get("rxSessionIdentifier");
        System.out.println("Corresponding RxSessionId is " +rxSessionIdentifier);
```

Comment: you need to write a loop to iterate over the `serviceLines.customerProducts` to find the record you're looking for

Comment: I tried doing that with the below code but I have an error customerProducts cannot be resolved or is not a field                                                             @Test
     private void HSIProductID (JsonPath js){
      
       for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
      if(js.get(serviceLines.customerProducts[i].highLevelProduct=="HSI") != null)
       {
        System.out.print(js.getString("serviceLines.customerProducts[i].customerProductIdentifier"));
       }

      } 
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following jsonpath query:

```
serviceLines[0].customerProducts.findAll{product -> product.highLevelProduct == 'HSI'}.customerProductIdentifier
```

Test:

```
System.out.println(js.get("serviceLines[0].customerProducts.findAll{product -> product.highLevelProduct == 'HSI'}.customerProductIdentifier").toString());
```

Note, that it will return list of identifiers in case your JSON contains several objects meeting your requirement.

Comment: I am getting below error  FAILED: Ensemble
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid JSON expression:
Script1.groovy: 1: expecting EOF, found '[' @ line 1, column 59.
   rviceLines[0].customerProducts[?(@.highL
                                 ^
1 error
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConst

Comment: Are you sure you're using the query I provided? As per your exception there is a parsing issue on position 59 where the parser encounters `[` character. But in my query there is `H` on that position.

Comment: Yes I am sure I am using the right path, The JsonPath shipped with rest assured is not using the same syntax as the json-path pseudo standard. It uses gpath. See documentation in the link https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured#Example_1_-_JSON

Comment: @MohammedAZahid check my update

Comment: Alexey R, you are awesome . That worked fine. Just that the output got printed within two square brackets. I wrote two lines of code just to remove them.